# Multiple processes created by OpenMP

Tags: openmp, thrust, libgomp

I tried out using OpenMP to parallelize a loop (using [Thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust) and [GOMP](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/gomp/) on Ubuntu) and was surprised to see multiple processes pop up in my process list. I had thought that OpenMP would spin up multiple threads, but not multiple processes.

Under what conditions does OpenMP spawn multiple processes?

Interestingly, my breakpoints on `fork` and `posix_spawn` were not hit. Is `htop` lying to me? (Each entry showed a unique PID.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being misled. Libgomp does not create processes.